# Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]

Tags: javascript, node.js, postgresql, express

I was wondering if anyone could help me with figuring out why I'm getting this error.

`Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]`

I'm trying to insert a row into a database with node/express. This is all new concepts to me and so it's likely that I'm missing something somewhat obvious here?

connect.js

```js
const {Client} = require('pg');

const client = new Client({
    connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
    ssl: {
        rejectUnauthorized: false,
    }
});

const createSpellTable = `
    CREATE TABLE spells (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        topic TEXT NOT NULL,
        date TEXT NOT NULL
    )
`;

client.query(createSpellTable, (err, res) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(`Error creating table: ${err.message}`);
    }else{
        console.log('Table created');
    }
});

const createOrderLuminos = `
    CREATE TABLE orderluminos (
        id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
        name TEXT NOT NULL,
        orderId TEXT NOT NULL
    )
`;

client.query(createOrderLuminos, (err, res) => {
    if(err){
        console.log(`Error creating table: ${err.message}`);
    }else{
        console.log('Table created');
    }
});

exports.storeSpellData = (req, res, next) => {
    const query = `
        INSERT INTO spells (name, topic, date)
        VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
        `;
    const values = [req.body.quickSpellsName, req.body.quickSpellsTopic, req.body.quickSpellsDate];

    client.query(query, values, (err, res) => {
        if(err){
            console.log(`Error inserting data: ${err.message}`);
            res.status(500).send({ error: 'Error inserting data' });
        }else{
            console.log(res.rows);
            next();
        }
    });
    client.end();
};

module.exports = {client};
```

app.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const database = require('./database/connect');

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

const homeRoute = require('./routes/index');
const submitRoute = require('./routes/submit');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use(homeRoute);
app.use(submitRoute);

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function () {
    console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", this.address().port, app.settings.env);
});

database.client.connect();
```

controllers/submits.js

```js
exports.getQuickSpells = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('quick-spells', {
        path: '/quick-spells',
        pageTitle: 'Quick Spells'
    });

};

exports.postQuickSpells = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('quick-spells', {
        path: '/quick-spells',
        quickSpellsName: req.body.quickSpellsName,
        quickSpellsTopic: req.body.quickSpellsTopic,
        quickSpellsDate: req.body.quickSpellsDate,
        pageTitle: 'Quick Spells'
    });
};

exports.getOrderLuminos = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('order-luminos', {
        path: '/order-luminos',
        pageTitle: 'Order Luminos'
    });
};

exports.postOrderLuminos = (req, res, next) => {
    res.render('order-luminos', {
        path: '/order-luminos',
        orderNumber: req.body.orderNumber,
        pageTitle: 'Order Luminos'
    });
};
```

routes/submit.js

```js
const express = require('express');
const db = require('../database/connect');
const submits = require('../controllers/submits');
const router = express.Router();

router.get('/quick-spells', submits.getQuickSpells);

router.post('/quick-spells', db.storeSpellData, submits.postQuickSpells);

router.get('/order-luminos', submits.getOrderLuminos);
router.post('/order-luminos', submits.postOrderLuminos);

module.exports = router;
```

I've tried setting up my router.post to look like this:

```js
router.post('/quick-spells', function (req, res, next){
    db.storeSpellData
    submits.postQuickSpells
});
```

and this omitted the error but when I try to send the form data it freezes in limbo forever.

Edit:

Here's the error log from the console

```
/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:211
        throw new Error(msg);
        ^

Error: Route.post() requires a callback function but got a [object Undefined]
    at Route.<computed> [as post] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:211:15)
    at proto.<computed> [as post] (/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:521:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/routes/submit.js:9:8)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:827:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/app.js:13:21)
```

Line 13 in app.js

```js
const submitRoute = require('./routes/submit');
```

Comment: Your `connects` module sets up all those exported functions, and then overrides all of them on the last line by setting `module.exports` to `{client}`.

Comment: Wow, thank you. That is a valuable lesson learned about exports!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution commented on by Pointy is correct.

Storing my `storeSpellData` function in a variable instead of exporting it directly like so:

```js
const storeSpellData = (req, res, next) => {
  const query = `
    INSERT INTO spells (name, topic, date)
    VALUES ($1, $2, $3)
  `;
  const values = [req.body.quickSpellsName, req.body.quickSpellsTopic, req.body.quickSpellsDate];

  client.query(query, values, (err, res) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(`Error inserting data: ${err.message}`);
    } else {
      console.log(res.rows);
      next();
    }
  });
  client.end();
};
```

and then just include it in the export below:

```js
module.exports = { client, storeSpellData };
```